# Gunicorn + Flask + Docker + Python

Tags: multithreading, docker, sockets, flask, gunicorn

In my application contain both server and client. I have implemented gunicorn in server. the server side contain 5 python files.I Implemented gunicorn in server.py.when server and client is connected , the details of clients available within function handle_client only, before applying gunicorn details of client can be accessed every where within Class.So I think there is a problem gunicorn with thread. please give me a proper solution. here I give you some code snippets

```
class StandaloneApplication(BaseApplication):

def __init__(self, app, options=None):
    self.options = options or {}
    self.application = app
    super().__init__()

def load_config(self):
    for key, value in self.options.items():
        if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None:
            self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

def load(self):
    return self.application
```

if **name** == "**main**":
try:

```
    # Start the TCP server
    server.start_tcp_server()

    # Start accepting connections in a separate thread
    accept_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.get_connections)
    accept_thread.start()


    options = {
        'bind': '%s:%s' % (server.server_host, server.web_port),
        'workers': multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1,  # Number of worker processes
        'threads': multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 ,
        'debug': False,
        'use_reloader': False,


        # Add more Gunicorn config options as needed
    }

    # Create an instance of StandaloneApplication
    gunicorn_app = StandaloneApplication(app, options)

    # Run Gunicorn with the StandaloneApplication
    gunicorn_app.run()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    event_logger.log_info("Server connection closed.")
finally:
    # Close the server socket and perform any other cleanup
    server.server_socket.close()
    sys.exit(0)
```